# Detecting External Wireless Remote Input In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, input, external, hardware-acceleration

So I need to get input from Logitech Wireless Presenter R400 which is a wireless clicker that is used in PowerPoint to present slides.

It has 2 buttons, next/previous. I need to get the button events in JavaScript so that I can use it to cycle through something.

If its not possible, is there a  way to link it with the keyboard right/left arrow keys?

I have been searching a lot and didnt find anything. Any way of getting external events to trigger something in javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: Using Javascript *in the browser*? I doubt it.

Comment: So no way? I've been searching a lot (and I know how to search) but I found nothing that could link external hardware to JavaScript.